# How to define global variables for a Terragrunt deployment

Tags: variables, terragrunt

How do I define/reference a set of variables to be re-used throughout my Terragrunt deployment? I'm currently specifying the same values (e.g., subscription, resource_group, environment, etc) in a `locals{}` block at each level of my deployment, but that seems completely opposite of the way to use Terragrunt.

My folder structure is similar to:

```
├── Folder A
│   └── main.tf
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── Folder B
│   └── main.tf
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
└── global_vars.yaml
└── main.tf
└── terragrunt.hcl
```

I read up on the [Locals](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/locals/) feature so created the global_vars.yaml in the root with contents such as:

```
environment = "prod"
```

and tried adding a block to the parent terragrunt.hcl:

```
locals {
  global_vars = yamldecode(file(find_in_parent_folders("global_vars.yaml")))
}
```

and then in the FolderA main.tf:

```
locals {
  ...
  environment = local.common_vars.environment
  ...
}
```

but I get errors that the local value with the name "global_vars" hasn't been declared.

To add another layer of fun, there's the possibility that I may want to override a given variable at a child level - but I feel like once I can tackle this declaration issue, the rest should be pretty easy (*...right?*).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was making it *way* too complicated. To fix this, I had to fix my yaml formatting to actually be a *map*:

```
locals:
  environment : "dev"
```

and add a line in the `locals{}` block of the children main.tf's with:

```
global_vars = yamldecode(file("../../global_vars.yaml"))
```

Then I reference the values like this:

```
environment = local.global_vars.locals.environment
```

There are probably prettier ways to do it, but this one is mine!